# when I execute the docker command I get "invalid reference format" error

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, docker-volume

How can I fix this problem?

> docker: invalid reference format.

I have executed this command:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 3000:8000 -env port=8000 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "c:/workspace/d/data-volumes-07-added-dockerignore/data-volumes-07-added-dockerignore:/app:ro" -v /app/node_modules -v /app/temp feedback-node:env
```

[image]

Comment: Is it important when I write "PORT" or "port"?

Comment: `-env` to `--env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten something in my command!
I changed `-env` to `--env`

```
docker run -d --rm -p 3000:8000 --env port=8000 --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "c:/workspace/d/data-volumes-07-added-dockerignore/data-volumes-07-added-dockerignore:/app:ro" -v /app/node_modules -v /app/temp feedback-node:env
```